# My Head Shows color, But Nothing Else Does On my Skin in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I uploaded a custom skin from Minecraft Skin Editor. I was playing my world when i switched to third person. My head still had colors, but the rest of my body was pitch black! I Re-uploaded my skin, but it didn’t change. I’m not sure what I did wrong. I was using a PC, and I didn’t have mods.

Comment: Without more information it's hard to tell what went wrong. It sounds like the sort of thing that might happen if your skin file was formatted weirdly, but if you were using an online skin maker that seems unlikely. The other possibility I can think of is that you somehow messed up the overlay layer and didn't notice, if you weren't doing much with it. More details about which exact site you were using and what you did would be helpful, I think. Also if you gave us the skin image (that is, the one you uploaded) that could give more information.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My Minecraft skin is broken (does not display correctly)](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/189360/my-minecraft-skin-is-broken-does-not-display-correctly) Or this: [Why is my Minecraft Skin Messed up?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/193047/why-is-my-minecraft-skin-messed-up)?